# Netsuite saved search sort by total items sold

Tags: search, netsuite

As the title states, I'm trying to sort a saved item search by how many of each item has been sold.  Problem is my search keeps timing out.  My problem is probably on the results tab where I'm tying to get the total sold by sum'ing the Transaction:Quantity field.  Does Netsuite hold this data somewhere else that I won't need to do any calculations?

Comment: It will help us if you can add any relevant info from your Criteria and Results tabs. The short answer, though, is "no" - NetSuite doesn't provide that information anywhere that I'm aware of. You calculate it from the transactions associated to the Item.

Comment: Criteria is looking for any item that has any one of three custom fields empty (using expressions with or).  Results tab is just the product code (group) and the transaction:quantity (sum)

Comment: That seems like the right approach for the Results, but are you sure you want ALL transactions (Sales Orders, Purchase Orders, Inventory Transfers, etc)? You may want to add a Criteria for `transaction.recordtype` so that you are truly only getting relevant Sales transactions.

Comment: In addition to Eric's suggestion if your custom fields are list/record fields you can select all of them (including "none") as an "anyof" operator and the search will be faster than an OR search. If not a List/Record you might still benefit from making the search use a formula numeric criteria and get rid of the expressions `case when {custitem_1} = 'bob' then 1 when {custitem_1} = 'carol' then 1 else 0 end`